# CSS background grids: horizontal repeating-linear-gradient with single vertical column

Tags: css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to create a specific background pattern on a single element using only CSS. The image below shows the end result I am aiming for:

[image]

I can create the repeating horizontal stripes using the following:

```
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(
                  to bottom,
                  #f7f7f8 0,
                  #f7f7f8 32px,
                  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 32px,
                  rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 64px
  );
```

But I am struggling to combine this with the vertical bar to the right. I'm not even sure if it's possible to achieve what I want... It needs to:

- Be a set distance, in pixels, from the right hand edge
- Be a fixed width, in pixels
- Completely overlay the horizontal grid beneath, ie. it should be the same color regardless of the underlying color- no transparency.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can lay 2 gradients on top of each others. first is always on top of next.

```css
html {
  min-height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(
      to left,
      transparent 140px,
      grey 140px,
      grey 143px,
      transparent 143px
    ),
    repeating-linear-gradient(
      to bottom,
      lightgrey 0,
      lightgrey 20px,
      transparent 20px,
      transparent 40px
    );
}
```

Comment: "first is always on top of next"- oh, that's what was throwing me off! I had assumed it was the other way round. Many thanks, this works perfectly :)